# How to change size of popup box in jquery fancy box v2.1.4?

Tags: jquery, html, css, popup, fancybox

I am using jquery fancy-box v2.1.4 (see the fancybox website [here](http://fancybox.net/)). Fancybox is working fine, but I am having trouble changing the size of pop up window. How can I control the size of the fancybox popup window?

Comment: All the information is in the API of the site you listed: http://fancybox.net/api specifically `height` and `width`

Comment: I used iframe class for pop up.

Comment: I am new to jquery. Can you give me any snippet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FancyBox as built in method to set width and height to the "window" generated to hold the content... check the website for further instructions, but here's a hit:

```
// initialize popup iframe (fancybox)
$(".yourframeclass").fancybox({
'autoDimensions': false,
'padding'       : 0,
'width'         : 940,
'height'        : 400,
'autoScale'     : false,
'transitionIn'  : 'none',
'transitionOut' : 'none',
 'type'          : 'iframe'
 });
```

Here I'm setting a popup with fixed 940px by 400px (it can be % values as well)... and if the content is larger then the fancybox holder, it will generate scroll bars on that same holder and not on the document itself!!!

Answer (score 1):

i dont know hopely this is useful.

```
$("yourSelector").fancybox({
    'width': 560, //change this value with width u want
    'height': 340 //change this value with height u want
});
```