# Fancybox on element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fancybox

I am trying to use fancybox in my application. I have

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.fancybox('#revolution');
    //$('#revolution').fancybox();
});
```

and if use the first line of fancybox, modal indeed pops up. If I comment out the first line and try using the second one, the revolution element is just appended at the end of the page.

The reason I need the second way to work is because I need change the size of the modal.

EDIT: using version 2.1.5. It doesn't need to pop-up immediately but it can.

Comment: What version are you using? And does it need to popup immediately?

Comment: Do you see any errors in browser developer tools console?

Comment: No, I'm not seeing any errors. Moreover, I want to add that it's a gsp page. However, in other pages the second version works perfectly fine so it's not a project setup problem.

Comment: @Ela : First you need to understand the difference between the fancybox **trigger** and the fancybox **target** (what you actually open in fancybox). In your first line of code, the `#revolution` selector is the **target**  while in the second is the **trigger** (which expects a `click` *event* to fire fancybox with whatever its target is). Check this for more http://stackoverflow.com/a/18579024/1055987

Comment: Thanks @JKF I understand the problem now however how do I do it when I want it to happen automatically rather than on click?

Answer (score -1):

FancyBox as built in method to set width and height

`$("#revolution").fancybox({
'autoDimensions': false,
'padding'       : 0,
'width'         : 940,
'height'        : 400
 });`

~ source https://stackoverflow.com/a/14872541/1479274

Comment: As I specified in my question, when I use $("#revolution").fancybox() the modal element is appended to the page rather than actually popping up and hence I can't change the width.